# Splitting multiple Dictionaries within a Pandas Column

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, analysis

I'm trying to split a dictionary with a list within a pandas column but it isn't working for me...

The column looks like so when called;

```
df.topics[3]
```

Output

```
"[{'urlkey': 'webdesign', 'name': 'Web Design', 'id': 659}, {'urlkey': 'productdesign', 'name': 'Product Design', 'id': 2993}, {'urlkey': 'internetpro', 'name': 'Internet Professionals', 'id': 10102}, {'urlkey': 'web', 'name': 'Web Technology', 'id': 10209}, {'urlkey': 'software-product-management', 'name': 'Software Product Management', 'id': 42278}, {'urlkey': 'new-product-development-software-tech', 'name': 'New Product Development: Software & Tech', 'id': 62946}, {'urlkey': 'product-management', 'name': 'Product Management', 'id': 93740}, {'urlkey': 'internet-startups', 'name': 'Internet Startups', 'id': 128595}]"
```

I want to only be left with the 'name' and 'id' to put into separate columns of topic_1, topic_2, and so forth.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: this is string you need ast.literal_eval convert it back

Comment: How do I convert it back? It was from an API that I called and put straight into csv

Comment: In the long run, you may be better off supplying a sample of what the API call returns and ask how to structure it into a dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give this a try.

```
import json
df.topics.apply(lambda x :  {x['id']:x['name'] for x in json.loads(x.replace("'",'"'))} )
```

Your output for the row you gave is :

```
{659: 'Web Design',
 2993: 'Product Design',
 10102: 'Internet Professionals',
 10209: 'Web Technology',
 42278: 'Software Product Management',
 62946: 'New Product Development: Software & Tech',
 93740: 'Product Management',
 128595: 'Internet Startups'}
```

Comment: Thanks ,I've tried that but I am receiving this error;  AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: Is your `df.topics[3]` a string or a list ?

Comment: A list. But no worries, I have fixed the issue

Comment: i want to reverse this process i have a data like {87: 'ARCADES',60: 'SHOES'} and need to convert as dataframe

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49335168/splitting-dictionary-list-inside-a-pandas-column-and-convert-as-new-dataframe

Answer (score 0):

You should try a simple method

```
    dt = df.topic[3]
    li = []
    for x in range(len(dt)):
       t = {dt[x]['id']:dt[x]['name']}
       li.append(t)
    print(li)
```

Output is-

```
    [{659: 'Web Design'},
    {2993: 'Product Design'},
    {10102: 'Internet Professionals'},
    {10209: 'Web Technology'},
    {42278: 'Software Product Management'},
    {62946: 'New Product Development: Software & Tech'},
    {93740: 'Product Management'},
    {128595: 'Internet Startups'}]
```

First we takes the value of **df.topic[3]** in `dt` which is in form of list and dictionary inside the list, then we take an temp list `li[]` in which we **add(append)** our values, Now we run the loop for the length of values of **de.topic(which we takes as dt)**, Now in `t` we are adding id or name by    `dt[0]['id']`  or `dt[0]['name']` which is `'659:'Web Design'` as x increase all values are comes in t, then by `{ : }` 
 we are converting the values in **Dictionary** and append it to the temporary list `li`