# Splitting dictionary/list inside a Pandas Column and convert as new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, data-analysis

I have data saved in a excel. I am querying this data using Python2.7 and turning it into a Pandas DataFrame. i have a column called category in my dataframe.It has a dictionary (or list?) of values within it. The DataFrame looks like this:

```
[1] df
ID                                          CATEGORY
1                                       {60: 'SHOES'}
2                                    {46: 'HARDWARE'}
3                                       {60: 'SHOES'}
4                          {219: 'GOVERNMENT OFFICE'}
5                         {87: 'ARCADES',60: 'SHOES'}
```

I need to split this column into separate columns so that the DataFrame looks like this:

```
[2] df2
CATEGORY_ID                   CATEGORY_NAME
60                                    SHOES
46                                 HARDWARE
219                       GOVERNMENT OFFICE
87                                  ARCADES
```

I need to add a new column in my dataframe

```
[3] df
ID           CATEGORY_id         
1                    60
2                    46
3                    60
4                   219 
5                 87,60
```

**Anyone please help me on this..**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need:

- `ast` for convert `string`s to `dictionaries`
- reshape by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)
- convert `index` to column by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)
- remove duplicates by [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)

---

```
import ast
df = (pd.DataFrame(df['CATEGORY'].apply(ast.literal_eval).values.tolist())
       .stack()
       .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
       .reset_index()
       .drop_duplicates()
       .rename(columns={'index':'CATEGORY_ID', 0:'CATEGORY_NAME'}))
print (df)
   CATEGORY_ID      CATEGORY_NAME
0           60              SHOES
1           46           HARDWARE
3          219  GOVERNMENT OFFICE
5           87            ARCADES
```

EDIT: Solution is a bit simplify, for joining dupplicates `CATEGORY_ID` use `groupby` with `join`:

```
import ast
df = (pd.DataFrame(df['CATEGORY'].apply(ast.literal_eval).values.tolist(), index=df['ID'])
       .stack()
       .reset_index()
       .rename(columns={'level_1':'CATEGORY_ID', 0:'CATEGORY_NAME'})
       )
print (df)
   ID  CATEGORY_ID      CATEGORY_NAME
0   1           60              SHOES
1   2           46           HARDWARE
2   3           60              SHOES
3   4          219  GOVERNMENT OFFICE
4   5           60              SHOES
5   5           87            ARCADES


df1 = df.groupby('ID')['CATEGORY_ID'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x.astype(str))).reset_index()
print (df1)
   ID CATEGORY_ID
0   1          60
1   2          46
2   3          60
3   4         219
4   5      60, 87
```

Comment: i updated the question i need one more thing please help me on this too

Comment: @Hrithu - need only `CATEGORY_ID` or also `CATEGORY_NAME` ?

Comment: CATEGORY_ID enough