# Splitting dictionary inside a Pandas Column into Separate Columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have data saved in a csv. I am querying this data using Python and turning it into a Pandas DataFrame. I have a column called team_members in my dataframe.It has a dictionaryof values. The column looks like so when called:

```
dt.team_members[1]
```

Output:

```
"[{'name': 'LearnFromScratch', 'tier': 'novice tier'}, {'name': 'Scratch', 'tier': 'novice tier'}]"
```

I tried to see this explanation and other similar:

[Splitting multiple Dictionaries within a Pandas Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47782052/splitting-multiple-dictionaries-within-a-pandas-column)

But they do not work

I want to get a column called name with the names of the members of the team and another with tier of each member.

Can you help me?

Thanks!!

Comment: It's easy enough to use `apply` or `map` to turn this into some other data structure. The better question is how did you end up with this in the first place?

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: A column with names: LearnFromScratch, Scratch. A and other with tier.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract name while looping over it

```
list(map(lambda x: x.get("name"), dt.team_members[1]))
```

if you need a new dataframe:
then follow @vivek answer:

```
pd.DataFrame(dt.team_members[1])
```

Comment: He wants to create a new dataframe not the list I believe.

Comment: exactly, i want a new df, with the dictionary values ​​in different columns.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the output of `dt.team_members[1]` is a list. 
If so, you can directly pass that list to create a dataframe something like:

```
pd.DataFrame(dt.team_members[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this-

```
    list = dt.team_member[1]
    li = []
    for x in range(len(list)):
       t = {list[x]['name']:list[x]['tier']}
       li.append(t)
    print(li)
```

Output is -

```
    [{'LearnFromScratch': 'novice tier'}, {'Scratch': 'novice tier'}]
```